# zsh notification of email (in maildir)

Tags: zsh, email

How can I modify the following so that it reads maildir and not just mailbox format?

```
typeset -a mailpath
for i in ~/Mail/Lists/*(.); do
   mailpath[$#mailpath+1]="${i}?You have new mail in ${i:t}."
done
```

Currently, I get:

```
/home/XXX/.zshrc:77: no matches found: /home/XXX/.Mail/Lists/*(.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enumerate the directories called `new` under `~/Mail/Lists/`. It's just a matter of a few [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `/` to match directories, and maybe `N` so that the expansion is empty if there is no match. Use `${i:h:t}` to show the name of the mailbox instead of `new`.

```
for i in ~/Mail/Lists/**/new(/N); do
  mailpath+=("${i}?You have new mail in ${i:h:t}.")
done
```

You can use the `e` glob qualifier to make this a one-liner, albeit a cryptic one.

```
maildirs+=(~/Mail/Lists/**/new(/Ne\''REPLY="${REPLY}?You have new mail in ${REPLY:h:t}."'\'))
```